# How do I archive Kafka message?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How can be archive Kafka messages like if we want to send a particular message to some topic so we archive that message and send to that topic or some other topic?

1. Can we replay that message to the topic?
2. Can we replay based on particular offset?

Comment: How are you defining "Archive"?

Comment: Can be archive kafka messages

Answer (score 0):

> send a particular message to some topic

That is a regular producer send request

> we archive that message

Kafka persists data for a configurable amount of time on its own. Default is a week

> send to that topic or some other topic

Again, a producer request can send to a specific topic. Kafka Streams or MirrorMaker can send to other topics, if needed

> replay that message to the topic

Not clear... Replay from where? Generally, read the message and produce to a topic

> replay based on particular offset

Yes, you can consume from a given TopicPartition + Offset coordinate within Kafka